# How do you remove guides in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, guides

In Adobe Photoshop (I'm currently using CS5), is it possible to remove the cyan-coloured guide lines? I'm talking about the ones added by `View > Guides.. >` [*horizontal/vertical guide choice*].

I can't find it anywhere on Google nor this site!

Comment: That is not what?

Comment: It IS the answer. This is the one solution that worked for me, unlike the other answers. I don't know what you're getting at but I think I can decide the right answer for myself, thank you.

Comment: P.s. The accepted answer was accepted by me *before* it got any points.

Comment: Use the command posted below. It's the easiest. "#;" It will only hide the guides. Use clear guides to remove

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Why did you edit the question? 'horizontal/vertical guide choice' is **not** a menu option which is why I made it italic.

Comment: I understand it isn't a choice but I was cleaning up the format.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I altered it a bit to make it clearer, if it's in grey it looks like it's a menu option :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do as Marc Edwards suggest, or you can also select an individual guide and drag it off the screen to delete it.

Answer (score 47):

Sure. You can hide the guides or clear them. Both can be done from the View menu.

[image: Hide Guides]

[image: Clear Guides]

Guides can also be turned on and off using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid for not having seen the 'clear guides' option. I decided to accept mrdwab's answer as the solution though, because removing them individually is actually what I had in mind. I voted yours up instead ;)

Comment: Oh yep, I should have included that. @mrdwab's suggestion is a good one :)

Answer (score 2):

You can select Clear Guides from the View menu, or if you have the rulers set as visible you can select and drag individual guides over top of the ruler and they will disappear.

Note that simply dragging the guides off the screen area may have worked in older versions of Photoshop (I'm not sure) but Photoshop CC will only erase the guide if the guide is dragged over top of the ruler.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To remove any guide from Photoshop, make sure that View > Lock Guides is deselected, then select the Move Tool and click and drag any guide and drag it anywhere past the canvas in a direction perpendicular to the guide and release it to delete it. You can also delete all guides at once, if necessary, by going to View > Clear Guides.

NOTE: If you're having trouble positioning guides just go to View > New Guide... and specify its offset from the side of the canvas in pixels.

*(tested on Adobe Photoshop CC, Version 14.0).*

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

For a faster way without losing your guides in case you need it later, just do apple+H (I'm sure its a combination of something+H in PC, maybe alt+H?)

It hides the guides, the same combo makes them visible again.

Comment: Ctrl+H, but that just hides, not remove them. Which was already mentioned by Marc btw ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about a shortcut you can use the combination of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> then press <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score -2):

**Keyboard shortcut tip**
Drag a horizontal guide and while in drag, hit the 'Alt' key this changes the guide to a vertical one. Releasing the 'Alt' key returns the guide back to horizontal.

Comment: Not really the answer to my question but a useful tip nonetheless, thanks.